# Get data from Microsoft Access table and put into Microsoft Excel workbook as QueryTable - powershell script failed

Tags: excel, powershell

**Here is my piece of code:**

```
$objExcel         = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $true
$objExcel.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
$objWorkBook      = $objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
$objWorkSheet     = $objWorkBook.Sheets.Item(1)
$objWorkSheet.Activate()

$strHome             = "C:\share"
$strAccessFile       = $strHome + "\db1.accdb"
$strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$strAccessFile;Persist Security Info=True;"

$adOpenStatic     = 3
$adLockOptimistic = 3

$objConnection = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection
$objConnection.Open($strConnectionString)
$objRecordSet  = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.RecordSet
$strAccessString = "SELECT * FROM Table"
$objRecordSet.Open($strAccessString,$objConnection,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic)

$objRecordSet.Fields.Item("Text").Value

$oRange = $objWorkSheet.Range("B4") 

$oRez = $objWorkSheet.QueryTables.Add($objRecordSet,$oRange)
```

Excel was opened, the same with Access recordset. Field "Text" value was shown.

**Last line of code produce error:**

```
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Parameter is not correct. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"
At C:\share\dataconn_test.ps1:26 char:1
+ $oRez = $objWorkSheet.QueryTables.Add($objRecordSet,$oRange)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

WHY? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: $numRecordsInserted = $objWorkSheet.Range("B4").CopyFromRecordSet($objRecordSet) - solution